# Getting error when I import LoginBackEnd module into settings.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using just phone number alone as the only field for login. So I am trying to write my custom backend authentication. On trying to import the LoginBackend module, I am getting the error below.

ERROR WHEN I CONFIGURE THE AUTH BACKENDS:

```
 File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def logins(request):
    phone_number = request.data.get("phone_number")
    if phone_number is None:
        return Response({'error': 'Please provide your phone number'},
                        status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    user = authenticate(phone_number=phone_number)
    if not user:
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid Credentials'},
                        status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return Response({'token': token.key},
                    status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

backends.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from .models import User

class LoginBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
        phone_number= kwargs['phone_number']
        user = User.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
        if user:
            return user
        else:
            return None
```

settings.py

```
from .backends import LoginBackend
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'findr.backends.LoginBackend']
```

Comment: `from .backends import LoginBackend` probably shouldn't be there in your settings

Comment: So what should be there? I have removed it and I still get the same error.

Comment: You shouldn't have either import there really

Comment: Alright. Thanks. Fixed it already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that was needed to get the stuff working was to undo the import statements in settings.py.